# Internal energy has excess translational energy excluded from it?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-statics, continuum-mechanics

So I was going through this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/214217/internal-energy-and-particle-fluid?fbclid=IwAR38SnxBwoj6XqrmgQbNcgTimHrZxemKfkr63SiaU5qtQe8YrlMcD2Do_wA#:%7E:text=In%20a%20fluid%2C%20the%20internal,potential%20energy) which states:

> In a fluid, the internal energy is the sum of the internal energy (in
> turn, the sum of the kinetic and potential energy) of each molecule

And I've seen many people state something similar. But this ends up confusing me. For simplicity, let's consider a system: a thermal gas in equilibrium inside a box and use [Euler's homogeneous function theorem to get](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60088/150174):

$$ U = TS - PV $$

where $U$ is the potential energy, $T$ is the temperature, $S$ is the entropy, $P$ is the pressure and $V$ is the volume.
Now, let us focus on the first term of the RHS:

$$ TS = -k_B T \sum_i p_i \ln p_i  $$
where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant and $p_i$ is the probability. Since $p_i = e^{-E_i/k_B T}$ ($E_i$ is the i'th energy state) then:

$$ TS = \sum_i p_i E_i $$

This is just your average energy of the volume considered. Now, let us think of the the term $PV$. The [pressure term only affects your center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#Pressure_and_kinetic_energy). The energy associated with it thus also be related to the center of mass. $K_{CM}$ is the translational kinetic energy associated with an ideal gas:

$$ \frac{3}{2} K_{CM} = PV $$

Thus internal energy has excess translational energy excluded from it?
I think I must be confusing something. Feel free to point out flaws in my argument.

Comment: $K_{\rm CM}$ is the translational kinetic energy, **relative to the centre of mass of the gas**, associated with an ideal gas